# Moving detection

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I'm using the following code to detect circles:

```
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0);
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
gray = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations=1)

gray = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=1)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 200,
                           param1=100, param2=50, minRadius=0, maxRadius=150)


if circles is not None:
    # Convert the (x,y) coordinate and radius of the circles
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    # Loop over the  (x,y) coordinate and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        # Draw the circle in the output
        cv2.circle(fancy_frame, (x+x1, y+y1), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
```

However, the circle is jumping when I detect. How can I sort this out? Is there any haar or svm to detect it?

This is the output that I'm getting:

[![Output][1]][1]

I want to detect all circles in realtime video

Comment: Post your result and expected result.

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: You have to apply some tracking algorithm, for example kalman-filter

Comment: @user1241241 I rolled back your edit. Did you mean to aks another question instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, most likely you just need to tweak [`HoughCircles` parameters](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles).

Start by lowering the `dp` parameter, it should give you more detections. I ran houghcircles.py from OpenCV samples folder on your image and it detects most of the rest of the circles:

```
$ python houghcircles.py your_image.png
```

[image: result]

Hough detection for circles is quite computation heavy so it might be hard to run this in real-time. Also "circles" on your image are far from perfect which doesn't make it easy for the algorithm. Consider training a neural network instead to detect these features.